# Count dynamic items

Tags: sql-server, split, count

I have a dynamic data Eg:

```
Name Date Class
______________
John 15/06/2019 AB
John 14/06/2019 B
John 13/06/2019 C
Tom  14/06/2019 C
Tom  13/06/2019 D
```

I want the result:

```
Name ClassA ClassB ClassC ClassD ClassCount
_____________________
John 1 2 1 0 4
Tom  0 0 1 1 2
```

I try someway,but it's not work.
thks.

Comment: what should be the logic for output as I am not able to see the relationship between data and output. Could you elaborate on logic part ?

Comment: the `Class` is it fix A to D only or dynamic ?

Comment: The class is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some dynamic SQL to execute to get your desired result. Check this following script.

**Note:** Considering class name A to Z

Check this [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=71d1eb72b3777f4133d23ada8eb61ed3) for more details.

```
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH CTE(Class,Name,Date)
AS
(
    SELECT A.Cl Class,B.Name,B.Date
    FROM (
        SELECT 'A' Cl UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'C' UNION ALL   SELECT 'D' UNION ALL SELECT 'E' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'F' UNION ALL SELECT 'G' UNION ALL   SELECT 'H' UNION ALL    SELECT 'I' UNION ALL    SELECT 'J' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'K' UNION ALL    SELECT 'L' UNION ALL    SELECT 'M' UNION ALL    SELECT 'N' UNION ALL    SELECT 'O' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'P' UNION ALL    SELECT 'Q' UNION ALL    SELECT 'R' UNION ALL    SELECT 'S' UNION ALL    SELECT 'T' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'U' UNION ALL    SELECT 'V' UNION ALL    SELECT 'W' UNION ALL    SELECT 'X' UNION ALL    SELECT 'Y' UNION ALL    SELECT 'Z' 
    )A
    INNER JOIN <your_table> B
    ON  B.Class LIKE '%' + A.Cl + '%'
)

SELECT  @ColumnList =
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ('],[' +  A.Class)
        FROM CTE A
        --ORDER BY (A.Class) 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')+']'
FROM CTE


SET @sqlCommand= 
N'
SELECT 
Name,A ClassA, B ClassB,C ClassC,D ClassD,
A+B+C+D ClassCount
FROM
(
    SELECT Name,'+SUBSTRING(@ColumnList,2,LEN(@ColumnList))+'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT A.Cl Class,B.Name,B.Date
        FROM (
            SELECT ''A'' Cl UNION ALL SELECT ''B'' UNION ALL SELECT ''C'' UNION ALL     SELECT ''D'' UNION ALL SELECT ''E'' UNION ALL
            SELECT ''F'' UNION ALL SELECT ''G'' UNION ALL   SELECT ''H'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''I'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''J'' UNION ALL
            SELECT ''K'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''L'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''M'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''N'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''O'' UNION ALL
            SELECT ''P'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''Q'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''R'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''S'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''T'' UNION ALL
            SELECT ''U'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''V'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''W'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''X'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''Y'' UNION ALL  SELECT ''Z'' 
        )A
        INNER JOIN <your_table> B
        ON  B.Class LIKE ''%'' + A.Cl + ''%''
    )A
    PIVOT(
        COUNT(Date)
        FOR Class IN('+SUBSTRING(@ColumnList,2,LEN(@ColumnList))+')
    )PVT    
)AA'


--PRINT @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```